# msvc's equivalent of gcc's __BASE_FILE__

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, macros

Is there any equivalent of `__BASE_FILE__` in Visual C++? I want to know name of the file *currently being compiled* by VC++.

Note: `__FILE__` expands into current file, e.g. it may be one of `#include`s.

---

From gcc's doc:

`__BASE_FILE__`

This macro expands to the name of the main input file, in the form of a C string constant. This is the source file that was specified as an argument when the C compiler was invoked.

Comment: I've usually been able to guess which source file from the output.  I'm presuming you just need to get to the root of compiler warnings and/or errors.  In the project's properties in Configuration Properties\C/C++\Advanced is the option to Show Includes.  It can also be set in a file's properties when you know the source file.

Comment: @John, no, I'm building custom memory leak detector (via overdefining `#define new new(__FILE__, __LINE__)`) for a embedded device. I'm facing now problem with `std::allocator` and friends - they are wrappers around `new` shadowing file/line of usage. Therefore, I've decided to try to bind to name of the translation unit, so at least initial direction of search would be known.

Comment: You could manually define __BASE_FILE__.  Try adding __BASE_FILE__=%(Filename) to the preprocessor defines in a project properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't look like there is an equivalent: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 12):

Thanks to John's comment, here is a workaround. If you simply put `__BASE_FILE__=%(Filename)`, it does not make a literal string. So put it between double quotes; I also added the extension since %(Filename) does not have it.

```
__BASE_FILE__="%(Filename)%(Extension)"
```

This line must be written in the preprocessor page of the property page of the project.